# Using jQuery + Ajax to load results of a form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm new to JS in general and wondering if anyone could help me get started with a little project idea I had.

I have an HTML form:

```
<form>
    <select>
        <option>Hunter</option>
        <option>Warrior</option>
    </select>

    <p></p>

    Stamina
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="stamina" placeholder="0"/>

    <p></p>

    <input type="submit" value="What stats will I receive?" />
</form>
```

I would like to know what HTML changes I need to make, and what JS code I will require, to be able to do the following:

- When user 'submits' the form, use jQuery and AJAX to print the results of the form just below with no page refresh.

  - The user must select an option from the select field to submit the form... if they don't then an error shows saying 'You must select something'.
  - If user enters the number '4' in the 'stamina' input, I want the script to multiply that number by ten and then print the result after form is submitted.
  - If user has selected 'Hunter', then I want the above behaviour to be different. If 'Hunter' is selected and then the number '4' entered in the 'stamina' input, I instead want it to multiply the number by 5 and then print the result after form is submitted.

I have jQuery referenced at the top of my page.

I have really gone through a lot of tutorials to try and find what I want but they are just too complicated for me - I stopped making websites in like 2008 and since then it seems frontend development has totally changed! If you could keep this in mind when responding I would appreciate it...

Teeb

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should change 'stamina' input type to `number` to prevent converting string to number. In your case one the hunter is selected by default, so it will never reach the message that says: 'You must type something'. If you want to have nothing selected by default you should add another option: `<option value="" selected>Select an option</option>`. Also options should have value:

`<option value="hunter">Hunter</option>`

Then your Jquery & Ajax code should look like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedValue = $('select').val();
    var stamina = $('input').val();
    if (!selectedValue) {
        return alert('You must select something!');
    }
    if (selectedValue === "hunter") {
      if (stamina == 4) {
        stamina = stamina * 5;
      }
    } else {
        if (stamina == 4) {
        stamina = stamina * 10;
      }
    }
    console.log('stamina: ' + stamina + ' | selected: ' + selectedValue);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: { 'stamina': stamina, 'value': selectedValue },
      dataType: dataType,
      success: function() {
        console.log('Submited!');
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Excellent response thank you for this! I will test it out later, just what I was hoping to find :) Just one thing - where I was talking about the stamina value being multiplied by 10 or by 5, what I want multiplied by 10 or 5 is the number that they input into the text field, as opposed to the arbitrary number 4 which I was using as an example. How would I do this?

Comment: @Teebling You are welcome. Okay, to achieve what you want if i did understood you well, is just by removing the `if` statements for stamina `if(stamina == 4)`, to just: `stamina = stamina *10;` & `stamina = stamina * 5`;

Comment: Hey Diamant, thanks for that. You understood me well :)

So I have this up in a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0d48zgw6/2/

But I can't see any console window so I don't know whether it was successful in processing the form and it looks like nothing happens - how can I make it so that it 'prints' the results in a <div> below the form? So when I press submit, I see the results below?

Do I add some code after success: function () { that prints the html i want?

Comment: @Teebling here is a link http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Take a few minutes to learn about Ajax. You did not set url variable tohe link you want to post that data in order to get a response.

Comment: Hey Diamant, it's OK I've realised I don't actually need to use AJAX to do what I want. Here is my updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vksgcy0h/

I have managed to get a result which I want to print below the form itself using innerHTML. Check it out! :)

However I am now trying to do the same with another input field 'Strength' included, but it doesn't seem to be working as intended - instead of doing the maths I tell it to do it is just getting the value of the 'stamina' input :(

Any help on this?